# Select all checkbox using 1 checkbox using bs-table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox, bootstrap-table

I have used bs-tables to pass selected row by checkbox but now i need to send all data when i select one checkbox.Below is my code which i have use to pass data of single and multiple rows.how to pass data of all rows by selecting single checkbox only.

```
<table id="eventsTable" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
            <th data-field="adate" data-align="center">Date</th>
            <th data-field="dc_no">DC. No.</th>
            <th data-field="customer_name" data-align="center">Customer Name</th>
            <th data-field="details" data-align="center">Description</th>
            <th data-field="plate_size" data-align="">Size</th>
            <th data-field="set" data-align="">Set</th>
            <th data-field="color" data-align="">Color</th>
            <th data-field="quantity" data-align="">Quantity</th>
            <th data-field="rate" data-align="">Rate</th>
            <th data-field="amount" data-align="">Total Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <?php foreach ($bill as $object) { ?>
            <td><!-- <input type="checkbox"> --></td>
        <td width="110px"><?php $date = $object['adate']; $newDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date)); echo $newDate;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $object['id'];?></td>
            <td width="18%"><?php echo $object['customer_name'];?></td>
            <td width="25%"><?php echo $object['details'];?></td>
            <td width="6%"><?php echo $object['plate_size'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $object['plate_set'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $object['color'];?></td>
            <td width="6%"><?php echo $object['quantity'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $object['rate'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $object['amount'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>  
    </tbody>


</table>
<div class="container text-center">
    <button id="add_cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button>
    <ul id="output"></ul>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var checkedRows = [];

    $('#eventsTable').on('check-all.bs.table', function (e, row) {
            $.checkedRows(checkedRows, function(index, value) {
            row.id.push({dc_no: row.dc_no, name: row.customer_name, adate: row.adate, plate_size: row.plate_size, set: row.set, color:row.color, qty: row.quantity, rate: row.rate, amount: row.amount, details: row.details});
            window.alert(checkedRows);
            // console.log(checkedRows);
        });
      });

    $('#eventsTable').on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {
      checkedRows.push({dc_no: row.dc_no, name: row.customer_name, adate: row.adate, plate_size: row.plate_size, set: row.set, color:row.color, qty: row.quantity, rate: row.rate, amount: row.amount, details: row.details});
      console.log(checkedRows);
      });

    $('#eventsTable').on('uncheck.bs.table', function (e, row) {
      $.each(checkedRows, function(index, value) {
      if (value.id === row.id) {
          checkedRows.splice(index,1);
        }
      });
    console.log(checkedRows);
  });
     var myRedirect = function(redirectUrl, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, value10) {
      var form = $('<form action="' + redirectUrl + '" method="post">' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="dc_no" value=" ' + value1 +'" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="customer_name" value=" ' + value2 +'" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="adate" value=" ' + value3 +'" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="plate_size" value=" ' + value4 +'" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="set" value=" ' + value5 +'" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value=" ' + value6 +'" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="rate" value=" ' + value7 +'" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value=" ' + value8 +'" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="details" value=" ' + value9 +'" />' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="color" value=" ' + value10 +'" />' +

        // '<input type="hidden" name="name" value="value.name" />' +
        '</form>');
        $('body').append(form);
        $(form).submit();
      };
    // $("#add_cart").click(function() {
    //     window.alert(JSON.stringify(checkedRows));
    // });

    $("#add_cart").click(function() {
    $("#output").empty();
    var dc = [];
    var custo = [];
    var ada = [];
    var ps = [];
    var set = [];
    var qty = [];
    var rate = [];
    var amnt = [];
    var details = [];
    var color = [];
    $.each(checkedRows, function(index, value) {
      // myRedirect("some", value.dc_no);
      var one = {dc_no: (value.dc_no)};
      var two = {customer_name: (value.name)};
      var three = {adate: (value.adate)};
      var four = {plate_size: (value.plate_size)};
      var five = {set: (value.set)};
      var six = {quantity: (value.qty)};
      var seven = {rate: (value.rate)};
      var eight = {amount: (value.amount)};
      var nine = {details: (value.details)};
      var ten = {color: (value.color)};
      // {dc_no: value.dc_no}
      var some1 = $.map(one, function(el) { return el;})
      dc.push(some1);

      var some2 = $.map(two, function(el) { return el;})
      custo.push(some2);

       var some3 = $.map(three, function(el) { return el;})
      ada.push(some3);

      var some4 = $.map(four, function(el) { return el;})
      ps.push(some4);

       var some5 = $.map(five, function(el) { return el;})
      set.push(some5);

      var some6 = $.map(six, function(el) { return el;})
      qty.push(some6);

       var some7 = $.map(seven, function(el) { return el;})
      rate.push(some7);

      var some8 = $.map(eight, function(el) { return el;})
      amnt.push(some8);

      var some9 = $.map(nine, function(el) { return el;})
      details.push(some9);

      var some10 = $.map(ten, function(el) { return el;})
      color.push(some10);
      // $('#output').append($('<li></li>').text(value.dc_no + " | " + value.name ));
    });

    // dc = $.toJSON(dc);
    var som1 = $.map(dc, function(el) { return el;})
    window.alert(som1);

    var som2 = $.map(custo, function(el) { return el;})
    window.alert(som2);

    var som3 = $.map(ada, function(el) { return el;})
    window.alert(som3);

    var som4 = $.map(ps, function(el) { return el;})
    window.alert(som4);

    var som5 = $.map(set, function(el) { return el;})
    window.alert(som5);

    var som6 = $.map(qty, function(el) { return el;})
    window.alert(som6);

    var som7 = $.map(rate, function(el) { return el;})
    window.alert(som7);

    var som8 = $.map(amnt, function(el) { return el;})
    window.alert(som8);

    var som9 = $.map(details, function(el) { return el;})
    window.alert(som9);

    var som10 = $.map(color, function(el) { return el;})
    window.alert(som10);



    // for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       //  var some = $.map(dc, function(el) { return el;})
       //  window.alert((some));
       myRedirect("some1",som1, som2, som3, som4, som5, som6, som7, som8, som9, som10);
    // }

    // myRedirect("some", value.dc_no);
  });


    </script>
```

Comment: What did you try till now? Please post your JavaScript code.

Comment: javaScript code is already present below the table tag.

Comment: Similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504643/check-uncheck-all-checkboxes-with-another-single-checkbox-use-jquery

Comment: yes @manny. it is similar question but i have used bs-table to select and select and pass the data. so i am trying to figure out how to do it with bs-table only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the select all event in BS table API.
For Example:

```
$('#eventsTable').on('all.bs.table', function (e, name, args) {
    console.log('Event:', name, ', data:', args);
})
```

The full example can be found here:
[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/36/)

For more exposure on this, you need to refer API documentation of BS table.