# How to check all Checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm Trying to check all elements if checkbox input type, I tried different solutions but it didn't work, I know this is simple, but I don't know what is wrong with my code:

```
<ul class="items">
  <li class="item checkall">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="checkAll">
      <span></span>
      <p>Check All Items</p>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="checkbox" value="1">
      <span></span>
      <p>Learn HTML5.1</p>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="checkbox" value="2">
      <span></span>
      <p>Learn PHP7</p>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="checkbox" value="4">
      <span></span>
      <p>Program a Website</p>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery :

```
$(".checkall").click(function () {
  $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: First use class instead of id. id must be unique and use `#id` for select an id and `.class` for select a class. And if you look better there's a lot of others question like you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537609/jquery-checkbox-check-all ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504643/check-uncheck-all-checkboxes-with-another-single-checkbox-use-jquery

Comment: Yes. It's simple. So, my question is: if you want to check all checkboxes, why do you need `not(this)` statement?

Comment: Use `change` event instead of `click`

Comment: @Alexis
I have looked for different questions, but I couldn't make it.

Comment: May it help! [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/z6sq1thx/#&togetherjs=o7bakMsrtA)

Comment: @Satpal
  change events isn't working

Comment: Where is you `.checkall` element? Is it a button or `checkbox`?

Comment: @RonyLoud thanks its working fine.

Comment: First of all, your code is not valid. I suggest you to take a quick tutorial about HTML and JS. Otherwise, you will meet a lot of problems like this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`id` for each element in a `HTML` page have to be unique. So either keep `unique id` or provide `class` for `checkbox` instead of `id` and `class` can be same. No uniqueness to maintain with `class`.

Attach on `click/change event` to `.checkAll` `checkbox` which has been changed to class here instead of `id` and set all `.checkbox` property based on the checked property of `.checkAll` checkbox. Below is the snippet.

```js
$(".checkAll").on('change',function(){
  $(".checkbox").prop('checked',$(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="items">
  <li class="item checkall">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" class="checkAll">
      <span></span>
      <p>Check All Items</p>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" class="checkbox" value="1">
      <span></span>
      <p>Learn HTML5.1</p>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" class="checkbox" value="2">
      <span></span>
      <p>Learn PHP7</p>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" class="checkbox" value="4">
      <span></span>
      <p>Program a Website</p>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your js to this:

```
$(".checkall").click(function (e) {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

And add class to your input not to `li` element:

```
<input class="checkall" type="checkbox" name="item[]" id="checkAll">
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/902swk1t/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".checkall").click(function (e) {

  var list = $(e.target).parents('ul');
  $('li:gt(0) label input:checkbox',list).attr('checked', this.checked);

});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @TobySpeight Ok sure, I will take care of these things next time on.